# Problema sobre cambio de variables

Tags: variables, arduino

Muy buenas a todos! Estoy haciendo un proyecto de un reloj el cual actualice la hora cada 24 horas conectándose a internet. Por lo tanto he decidido tomar un DS3231 para llevar la hora  y un ESP32 para actualizarla cada 24 horas mediante un servidor NTP.

El problema es que no se porque en el código no me deja asignar los valores que recepciono del servidor NTP a los del RTC (a una hora determinada del día, la cual se encuentra en un if), resulta algo así como que no son la misma variable.

Adjunto el código por si a alguno se le ocurre alguna solución. Creo que el problema esta en las líneas siguientes:

```
fecha.hour()=timeClient.getHours();
fecha.minute()=timeClient.getMinutes();
fecha.second()=timeClient.getSeconds();
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <NTPClient.h>
    #include <WiFiUdp.h>
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include "RTClib.h"
    
    WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
    NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP);
    RTC_DS3231 rtc;
    
    // Variables to save date and time
    
    String formattedTime;
    String dayStamp;
    String timeStamp;

    void setup() {
      // Initialize Serial Monitor
      Serial.begin(115200);
      
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    
      // Initialize a NTPClient to get time
      timeClient.begin();

      timeClient.setTimeOffset(3600+3600);
    
      // Initialize a DS3231 to get time
      if (! rtc.begin()) {
        Serial.println("RTC no encontrado!");
        while(1);
      }
      
      rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    }


    void loop() {
      DateTime fecha = rtc.now();
      
      while(!timeClient.update()) {
        timeClient.forceUpdate();
      }
      // The formattedDate comes with the following format:
      // 2018-05-28T16:00:13Z
      // We need to extract date and time
      formattedTime = timeClient.getFormattedTime();
    
        if((timeClient.getHours()==13) && (timeClient.getMinutes()==39)){
              Serial.print("Formatted Time: ");
              Serial.println(formattedTime);  
        
              fecha.hour()=timeClient.getHours();
              fecha.minute()=timeClient.getMinutes();
              fecha.second()=timeClient.getSeconds();
        
          // Extract date
      }

      Serial.print(fecha.hour());
      Serial.print(':');
      if(fecha.minute() < 10){
        Serial.print("0");
      }
      Serial.print(fecha.minute());
      Serial.print(':');
      if(fecha.second() < 10){
        Serial.print("0");
      }
      Serial.print(fecha.second());
    
      Serial.println();
      delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!